# PubNub: Top level wildcard can be added only if no other event handlers exist for given key and event

Tags: pubnub

**I Have two types of dynamic channel ids:**

1. **private.x** (where x is an Integer)
2. **public.x** (where x is an Integer)

**I'm trying to create two PubNub After-Publish-Or-Fire Functions:**

1. ***Bot***: use for getting Bot reply for the private channels using wild card: private.* (function call to an api on my server and get a Bot reply to publish).
2. ***Log***: use for log all messages using wild card: * (function call to an api on my server with a message and save it to my db).

**The problem is that it seems that PubNub cannot support two functions on a same channel. and event types**

**My questions:**

1. I don't want the log function to log only the public.* channels and that the Bot function will do both Bot and Log actions on the private.* channels. Is There other way to bypass this limitation?
2. Do both **Before-Publish-Or-Fire** and **After-Publish-Or-Fire** events async? (maybe I can use the **Before-Publish-Or-Fire** for the Log function and **After-Publish-Or-Fire** for the Bot)?

Comment: Hi @tomn we are reviewing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PubNub Wildcards can be added only if no other event handlers exist for given key and event

You want to reuse code in two event handlers.  You provided your own answer. Your answer is an acceptable approach in your original question.  And we have provided an additional way you may consider for solving this.

- Log action on the `public.*` channels.
- Bot and Log actions on the `private.*` channels.

You can create a `log` channel which is invoked by a fire.  Inside the `public.*` and `private.*` functions you will trigger a fire invoking the `log` channel event handler.  This way you have shared code reuse for your logging mechanism.

[image: Multiple Channels for Logging Data to your Server]

### Async vs Sync Events

> **Question:** Are both `Before-Publish-Or-Fire` and `After-Publish-Or-Fire` events async?
>
> **Answer:** No.  Only `on-after` events are async.

A natural way to think about this is that anything that needs to happen `before` must be blocking and non-async.  Otherwise it couldn't [happen before, and may end up happening after](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/working-with-the-event-handler-types-advanced-functions-techniques/).

### Before and After Events

> **Question:** Can you use the `Before-Publish-Or-Fire` for the BOT function and `After-Publish-Or-Fire` for Logging)?
>
> **Answer:** Yes!  This is a great way to do it.

[image: Before and After Event on the same PubNub Channel]